# Shell script taking longer for compression along with find

Tags: bash, shell

I am having problem with my shell script where i am trying to zip a folder of 20GB size and it took almost 11 hours for me to zip all folders maintaining it's path. I have one search filter where i want to zip only xml files. Is there anyway to optimize this script so that it doesn't take longer then what it is taking -

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE_TIME="$(date '+%m%d%Y_%H%M%S')"
DATE="$(date '+%m%d%Y')"

#Create a backup directory
BACKUPDIR="/Backup_$1_$DATE_TIME"
LOGDIR="/Logs"
mkdir -p .$BACKUPDIR/$1/$LOGDIR

zipPath="dev/BackupTest"
logPath="/dev/BackupTest$BACKUPDIR/$1$LOGDIR"


cd /prod/$1 

for f in *
do       
 nohup find . | grep *.xml | zip -r $zipPath$BACKUPDIR/${1}/"${f}.zip" "$f" > $logPath/${f}.log 2>&1 ; 

done
```

Comment: `for f in *`, you run `find .`, so you're recursing finding all files (not just in the one directory) for each top-level file.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to run `find "$f"`? But even then, you should **never** run `find | grep`; instead, tell `find` to do the filtering itself.

Comment: `find "$f" -name '*.xml' -exec zip -r "$zipPath/$f.zip" "$f" {} + >"$logPath/$f" 2>&1`

Comment: (BTW, what's the point of `nohup` here? Using bash's built-in `disown` gives you more control, but if you aren't backgrounding the task, protecting it from HUPs whether with `nohup` or `disown -h` makes little difference).

Comment: ...anyhow, if you *looked in* your zip files, and saw that they all had the same files, it probably would have saved the need to ask a question here.

Comment: ...note too that `grep *.xml` is going to have hard-to-predict behavior, since it lists all the xml files in the current directory and passes their names as arguments to `grep`; thus, what files (if any) match that pattern in the current directory has a serious impact on what your pipeline actually does. If you wanted to grep for files whose names *ended* in .xml, that might be `grep -E '[.]xml$'`, but, again, don't do that when you can have `find` doing the filtering on its end.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am going to try the command that you suggested after my previous run is finished. The way my folder structure is that there is parent folder that consists of many subfolders consisting of xml, json, txt files. Out of this folders i only wanted to get xml files and zip the subfolders. Looking at my zip folders i do see that different zip folders have different zip files. But i never thought of using find to do the filtering itself. Let me give that a shot and see what i come up with. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You're running the same `nohup find . | grep *.xml | zip` command no matter what value `$f` is. How would they *not* all have the same files, unless your `zip` isn't reading its list of files from stdin at all (such that the `find` and `grep` aren't doing anything at all)?

Comment: ...oh. Heh. Actually, thinking about it, you're *only* `nohup`ing `find`, not the rest of the pipeline, so `grep` has no input at all, so `zip` has no stdin, so the `find . | grep` *always was* a red herring, with no impact on the rest of the pipeline's behavior.